# PDFMake: Unable to save pdf file on android device

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, pdfmake

Unable to save pdf file on android which is created using PDFMake library.

In my ionic app, I am not able to download pdf which I created using PDFMake library even it log success. Here I am trying to writeFile using file module, when user click on generatePdf button

Since last two days I am trying to achieve this.. but no luck, so now I am looking for some help here.

component.html

```
<ion-button (click)="generatePdf()">generatePdf</ion-button>
```

component.ts

```
generatePdf() {
let self = this;
const pdfData = {
  content: [
    'First paragraph',
    'Another paragraph',
  ],
};

let pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(pdfData);
pdfDocGenerator.getBuffer((buffer) => {
  let utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  let binaryArray = utf8.buffer;
  self.saveToDevice(binaryArray, 'first.pdf');
});
}

saveToDevice(data: any, savefile: any) {
  let self = this;
  self.file.writeFile(self.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, savefile, data, { replace: false 
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success...');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error...');
  });
 }
```

Comment: Tell full path of file that you try to write. Also tell error messages and exceptions.

Comment: @blackapps, File path doesn't matter, I just want to save the file which can be visible in downloads/files folder. And currently I am getting success... console, without any saved file.